# limit to the number of digits 

Tags: truncate, digits, scilab

my project is to create a program that will test whether a number is prime or not. the code is ready. but when i enter a 19 digit prime for example, the code immediately outputs "composite". i'm quite sure it is because it treats the last few digits of the number as zeroes. is there a way to store more than 16 digits in scilab?

Comment: Use SciPy instead ;) Python has a BigInt

Answer (score 1):

The output is a just a formating thing. Scilab does store all the value. 
format(25) will increase the display size.